# How do I stretch a strip to work with the speed control effect without loosing footage?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, effects

I have a video clip and I made two cuts (I can choose between **soft- and hardcuts**, but I do not know the difference). I would like to play the part of the clip between the two cuts in slow motion, so I added an **effect strip** on it called **speed control** and changed the speed to .25 of the original speed.

---

It works in so far, that the speed is indeed slower, but there is a problem:

---

Since this part is playing only .25 of the speed of the original, the part should be expanded to 4 times its original lenght, but the length stays the same and so when I play the clip, the part with the applied effect shows only the first quarter of the original part without the effects.

Comment: Video Tutorial ... which I have not watched for this particular question.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYfP357K4y8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Click and Drag on the End part of the clip with the minimal arrow to manually stretch it out and extend.  Make sure there is empty room to extend.  Use the correct side of mouse to click.  My mouse is differently set.

The panel also allows you to type in length. Press <kbd>n</kbd> to display panel.

Middle Click moves the entire strip. Do not click in the Middle for this task.

Comment: I cut a strip out of a larger strip and when extending, instead of stretching the strip, it adds the difference from the original strip.